# Show div when enter the site, but hide when li is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Scenario**

I have a list based on Isotope, which sorts out products within each category. This is done by `data-filter`. I have also added script that shows/hides text, `onclick="toggle_visibility('#')"`.

In `header.php` I have the following:

```
<script>
   function toggle_visibility(id) {
      var all = document.getElementsByClassName('category');
      for(var i = 0; i < all.length; i++)
      all[i].style.display = (all[i].id == id && all[i].style.display == 'none')
      ? 'block' : 'none';
   }
</script>
```

On the page (`archive.php`) with the list I have the following:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href='#' data-filter='.familiepakker' class="smoothtrans" onclick="toggle_visibility('familiepakker')">Familiepakker</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' data-filter='.effektbatterier' onclick="toggle_visibility('effektbatterier')">Effektbatterier</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' onclick="toggle_visibility('produktslider')">Produktslider</a></li>
    <!-- And so on -->
</ul>
<div id="familiepakker" class="category" style="display:none;">Text</div>
<div id="effektbatterier" class="category" style="display:none;">Text</div>
<!-- And so on -->

<div id="produktslider" class="category" style="display:none;">
    <div class="container">
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[all_around id="1"]'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works great right now. However `#produktslider` is only going to be shown when the user enters the page. When a `li` is clicked, it should disappear.

Right now it appears only when a `li` is clicked. The `li` is not going to be there, and was just added as a test.

You can take a look at the page [here](http://vekvemedia.no/oppdrag/spectra-norge/fyrverkeri/).

Do you have any ideas, or a working solution? Please ask if I am being unclear.

**Edit:**

Sorry for being unclear. I want "produktslider" to be visible when the user enters the site. When the user clicks on a `li`it should dissapear. This means that "produktslider" is only going to be visible when the users enters the page.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Do you want the "produktslider" to always be visible? Or only visible when the user clicks on an `li`?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I want "produktslider" to be visible when the user enters the site. When the user clicks on a `li`it should dissapear. This means that "produktslider" is only going to be visible when the users enters the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is extremely simple,
Change default style of produckslider from `display:none` to `display:block` as in:

```
<div id="produktslider" class="category" style="display:block;">
```

This will cause productslider to be visible by default.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am feeling so blind that I didn't see that.